# Create counter of consecutive runs of a certain value

Tags: r, sequence, run-length-encoding

I have data where consecutive runs of zero are separated by runs of non-zero values. I want to create a counter for the runs of zero in the column 'SOG'.

For the first sequence of 0 in SOG, set the counter in column Stops to 1. For the second run of zeros, set 'Stops' to 2, and so on.

```
SOG Stops
--- -----
4   0
4   0
0   1
0   1
0   1
3   0
4   0
5   0
0   2
0   2
1   0
2   0
0   3
0   3
0   3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SOG <- c(4,4,0,0,0,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,0,0,0)
#run length encoding:
tmp <- rle(SOG)
#turn values into logicals
tmp$values <- tmp$values == 0
#cumulative sum of TRUE values
tmp$values[tmp$values] <- cumsum(tmp$values[tmp$values])
#inverse the run length encoding
inverse.rle(tmp)
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 df$stops<- with(df, cumsum(c(0, diff(!SOG))>0)*!SOG)
 df$stops
 # [1] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df <- df %>% mutate(Stops = ifelse(SOG == 0, yes = cumsum(c(0, diff(!SOG) > 0)), no = 0))
 df$Stops
 #[1] 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 3
```

EDIT: As an aside to those of us who are still beginners, many of the answers to this question make use of logicals (i.e. TRUE, FALSE).  `!` before a numeric variable like `SOG` tests whether the value is `0` and assigns `TRUE` if it is, and `FALSE` otherwise.

```
SOG
#[1] 4 0 0 0 3 4 5 0 0 1 2 0 0 0
!SOG
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[12]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`diff()` takes the difference between the value and the one before it.  Note that there is one less element in this list than in `SOG` since the first element doesn't have a lag with which to compute a difference.  When it comes to logicals, `diff(!SOG)` produces `1` for `TRUE - FALSE = 1`, `FALSE - TRUE = -1`, and `0` otherwise.

```
diff(SOG)
#[1] -4  0  0  3  1  1 -5  0  1  1 -2  0  0
diff(!SOG)
#[1]  1  0  0 -1  0  0  1  0 -1  0  1  0  0
```

So `cumsum(diff(!SOG) > 0)` just focuses on the `TRUE - FALSE` changes

```
cumsum(diff(!SOG) > 0)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

But since the list of differences is one element shorter, we can append an element:

```
cumsum(c(0, diff(!SOG) > 0))  #Or cumsum( c(0, diff(!SOG)) > 0 ) 
#[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

Then either "multiply" that list by `!SOG` as in `@akrun`'s answer or use the `ifelse()` command.  If a particular element of `SOG == 0`, we use the corresponding element from `cumsum(c(0, diff(!SOG) > 0))`; if it isn't `0`, we assign `0`.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner with `rle` would be -

```
df <- data.frame(SOG = c(4,4,0,0,0,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,0,0,0))
df <- transform(df, Stops = with(rle(SOG == 0), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths)))
df

#   SOG Stops
#1    4     0
#2    4     0
#3    0     1
#4    0     1
#5    0     1
#6    3     0
#7    4     0
#8    5     0
#9    0     2
#10   0     2
#11   1     0
#12   2     0
#13   0     3
#14   0     3
#15   0     3
```