# Consecutive group number in R

Tags: r

This problem is very similar to [Consecutive value after column value change in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077228/consecutive-value-after-column-value-change-in-r)

So for

```
SOG <- c(4,4,0,0,0,3,4,5,0,0,1,2,0,0,0)
```

the difference is that now I'd like to count how many groups of SOG there are. For example:

```
SOG Trips
--- ----- 
4    1
4    1     
0    0
0    0
0    0
3    2
4    2
5    2
0    0
0    0
1    3
2    3
0    0
0    0
0    0
```

Anyone?

Comment: what constitutes a group?

Comment: `r <- rle(SOG !=0) ; r$values[r$values] <- cumsum(r$values[r$values]) ;
inverse.rle(r)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean a "group of SOG" is a set of consecutive non-zero SOG values, i.e. starts with a non-zero SOG value and ends with a non-zero SOG value (not necessarily the same value):

```
Trips <- ifelse(SOG>0, cumsum(c(SOG[1]>0, diff(SOG>0)) == 1), 0)
# [1] 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one option:

```
replace(cumsum(c(SOG[1], abs(diff(SOG))) == SOG & SOG != 0), SOG == 0, 0)
# [1] 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try my [`TrueSeq`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/TrueSeq.R) function from [my GitHub-only "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

Usage would be:

```
library(SOfun)
TrueSeq(as.logical(SOG))
#  [1] 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 0 0 0
```

To get the inverse, just negate the `as.logical` step:

```
TrueSeq(!as.logical(SOG))
#  [1] 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 3
```