# Create group number for runs of non-NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, run-length-encoding

I have the following dataframe df (`dput` below):

```
> df
   id value
1   1     1
2   2     3
3   3     2
4  NA     1
5  NA     3
6   8     4
7   9     2
8  10     1
9  NA     1
10 NA     3
11 15     2
12 16     1
13 NA     3
14 NA     4
15 NA     2
16 20     1
17 21     1
18 22     3
19 NA     2
20 NA     1
21 NA     3
22 66     4
23 67     2
24 68     1
```

For each consecutive run of non-`NA` "id", I would like to create a unique group ID (variable "id2" in the example). For the `NA` in between, the "id2" should be `NA`.

In the example, the first run of non-`NA` "id" (1, 2 and 3), should all belong to group 1 (id2 = 1). The `NA` on row 4-5 should have id2 = `NA`. The second run of non-`NA` "id" (8, 9, 10) should have id2 = 2, and so on.

The desired output should look like this:

```
   id value id2
1   1     1   1
2   2     3   1
3   3     2   1
4  NA     1  NA
5  NA     3  NA
6   8     4   2
7   9     2   2
8  10     1   2
9  NA     1  NA
10 NA     3  NA
11 15     2   3
12 16     1   3
13 NA     3  NA
14 NA     4  NA
15 NA     2  NA
16 20     1   4
17 21     1   4
18 22     3   4
19 NA     2  NA
20 NA     1  NA
21 NA     3  NA
22 66     4   5
23 67     2   5
24 68     1   5
```

As you can see, id2 shows the unique id I want for the values of id between NA. It may be that there is only a `NA` after the values, like for id's 1, 2 and 3. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to create a unique ID for values between `NA`'s?

---

`dput` of df:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 8, 9, 10, NA, NA, 15, 
16, NA, NA, NA, 20, 21, 22, NA, NA, NA, 66, 67, 68), value = c(1, 
3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 
2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Related: [Create counter of consecutive runs of a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077228/create-counter-of-consecutive-runs-of-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a possibility, maybe not the most efficient:

1. find the transitions between a valid `id` and an `NA`. That gives you a `1` each time we have an `id` which is `NA` but the previous one is valid.
2. make the cumulative sum
3. add `NA` where needed

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA, 8, 9, 10, NA, NA, 15, 
                            16, NA, NA, NA, 20, 21, 22, NA, NA, NA, 66, 67, 68), value = c(1, 
                                                                                           3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 
                                                                                           2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

df |> 
  mutate(
    id2 = as.numeric(is.na(id) & !is.na(lag(id))),
    id2 = cumsum(id2) + 1,
    id2 = ifelse(is.na(id), NA, id2)
  )
#>    id value id2
#> 1   1     1   1
#> 2   2     3   1
#> 3   3     2   1
#> 4  NA     1  NA
#> 5  NA     3  NA
#> 6   8     4   2
#> 7   9     2   2
#> 8  10     1   2
#> 9  NA     1  NA
#> 10 NA     3  NA
#> 11 15     2   3
#> 12 16     1   3
#> 13 NA     3  NA
#> 14 NA     4  NA
#> 15 NA     2  NA
#> 16 20     1   4
#> 17 21     1   4
#> 18 22     3   4
#> 19 NA     2  NA
#> 20 NA     1  NA
#> 21 NA     3  NA
#> 22 66     4   5
#> 23 67     2   5
#> 24 68     1   5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `rle` + `cumsum` + `replace`

```
transform(
  df,
  id2 = replace(with(
    rle(!is.na(id)),
    rep(cumsum(values), lengths)
  ), is.na(id), NA)
)
```

or a more concise one `with(rle(!is.na(id)), rep(cumsum(values) * NA^!values, lengths))` (Thanks for the comment from Henrik), which
could give

```
   id value id2
1   1     1   1
2   2     3   1
3   3     2   1
4  NA     1  NA
5  NA     3  NA
6   8     4   2
7   9     2   2
8  10     1   2
9  NA     1  NA
10 NA     3  NA
11 15     2   3
12 16     1   3
13 NA     3  NA
14 NA     4  NA
15 NA     2  NA
16 20     1   4
17 21     1   4
18 22     3   4
19 NA     2  NA
20 NA     1  NA
21 NA     3  NA
22 66     4   5
23 67     2   5
24 68     1   5
```

Comment: Similar: `with(rle(!is.na(id)), rep(cumsum(values) * NA^!values, lengths))`

Comment: @Henrik yes, that more elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In an inelegant (mostly) base R approach, you can `split` on the NA values and `do.call(rbind,...)` to bring together then clean up the group assignments. "Mostly" base R since I used `data.table::rleid()` for the final group names:

```
# Assign group values
df$id2 <- NA
ll <- split(df, cumsum(is.na(df$id)))
ll2 <- lapply(seq_along(ll), function(x) {ll[[x]]$id2 <- x; ll[[x]]})

# Combine and clean up
comb <- do.call(rbind, ll2)
comb[is.na(comb$id),"id2"] <- NA
comb$id2[!is.na(comb$id2)] <- data.table::rleid(comb$id2[!is.na(comb$id2)])
```

Output:

```
   id value id2
1   1     1   1
2   2     3   1
3   3     2   1
4  NA     1  NA
5  NA     3  NA
6   8     4   2
7   9     2   2
8  10     1   2
9  NA     1  NA
10 NA     3  NA
11 15     2   3
12 16     1   3
13 NA     3  NA
14 NA     4  NA
15 NA     2  NA
16 20     1   4
17 21     1   4
18 22     3   4
19 NA     2  NA
20 NA     1  NA
21 NA     3  NA
22 66     4   5
23 67     2   5
24 68     1   5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp := rleid(!is.na(id))][!is.na(id), id2 := .GRP, grp][, grp := NULL]
```

-output

```
> df
    id value id2
 1:  1     1   1
 2:  2     3   1
 3:  3     2   1
 4: NA     1  NA
 5: NA     3  NA
 6:  8     4   2
 7:  9     2   2
 8: 10     1   2
 9: NA     1  NA
10: NA     3  NA
11: 15     2   3
12: 16     1   3
13: NA     3  NA
14: NA     4  NA
15: NA     2  NA
16: 20     1   4
17: 21     1   4
18: 22     3   4
19: NA     2  NA
20: NA     1  NA
21: NA     3  NA
22: 66     4   5
23: 67     2   5
24: 68     1   5
```

---

or in `base R`

```
inverse.rle(within.list( rle(!is.na(df$id)), {
 values[values] <- seq_along(values[values])
  values[!values] <- NA}))
```