# Taking mean of consequitive non NA values in data table in R

Tags: r

For the below data table

```
library(data.table)

test = data.table(date = c("2006-01-31", "2006-03-20", "2006-03-28", "2006-05-03", "2006-05-04", "2006-06-29", "2006-09-11"), value = c(NA, -0.028, NA, 0.0245, -0.008, NA, -0.009))
```

I need the mean of consequitive Non NA values as a separate column in the above data table.
For eg, the resultant data table would look like this

```
library(data.table)

test = data.table(date = c("2006-01-31", "2006-03-20", "2006-03-28", "2006-05-03","2006-05-04", "2006-06-29", "2006-09-11"), value = c(NA, -0.028, NA, 0.0245, -0.008, NA, -0.009), value_new = c(NA, -0.028, NA,0.008, 0.008, NA, -0.009))
```

Tried doing this using rle and data table functions but not getting the correct output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, got the solution from this thread

[Create group number for runs of non-NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75803671/create-group-number-for-runs-of-non-na-values)

```
test[ , grp := rleid(is.na(Net_Sentiment_LM_d))][!is.na(Net_Sentiment_LM_d), Net_Sentiment_LM_d_new := mean(Net_Sentiment_LM_d), grp]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the running mean of non-NA's we can use`cumsum()`combined with `seq_len()`:

```
library(data.table)

test[!is.na(value), value_new := cumsum(value) / seq_len(.N)]

         date   value    value_new
1: 2006-01-31      NA           NA
2: 2006-03-20 -0.0280 -0.028000000
3: 2006-03-28      NA           NA
4: 2006-05-03  0.0245 -0.001750000
5: 2006-05-04 -0.0080 -0.003833333
6: 2006-06-29      NA           NA
7: 2006-09-11 -0.0090 -0.005125000
```

Comment: i dont need running mean. only the mean for the set of consequent non-NA values per group